# PrintWriter not writing to file, tried adding flush() and close() Java

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

Tried to write to a file. Did my research, made sure to flush and close. I thought that perhaps it was reading the message box blank and was writing nothing, but did a System.out.println to make sure it was reading correctly, and it is. so Not sure now.

Original Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Form extends Applet implements ActionListener{
private TextField first = new TextField("First Name",12);
private TextField middle = new TextField("I",1);
private TextField last = new TextField("Last Name",15);
private TextField address = new TextField("Address",25);
private TextField city = new TextField("City",20);
private TextField state = new TextField("State",2);
private TextField zip = new TextField("Postal Code",10);
private Button submit =new Button("Submit");
private Button reset = new Button("Reset");
private Button save = new Button("Save");
private Button enlarge = new Button("Enlarge");
private TextArea message = new TextArea();


public void init()
{
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    setLayout(gbl);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.weightx=1.0;
    c.weighty=1.0;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    gbl.setConstraints(first,c); add(first);
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gbl.setConstraints(middle,c); add(middle);
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(last,c); add(last);
    c.gridy=1;
    gbl.setConstraints(address,c); add(address);
    c.gridy=2;
    gbl.setConstraints(city,c); add(city);
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gbl.setConstraints(state,c); add(state);
    c.gridy=3;
    gbl.setConstraints(zip,c); add(zip);
    c.gridy=4;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbl.setConstraints(submit,c);add(submit);
    gbl.setConstraints(reset,c); add(reset);
    c.gridy=5;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbl.setConstraints(save, c); add(save);
    gbl.setConstraints(enlarge, c); add(enlarge);
    c.gridy=6;
    c.gridwidth=3;
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbl.setConstraints(message,c);add(message);
    submit.addActionListener(this);
    reset.addActionListener(this);
    enlarge.addActionListener(this);
    save.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{

    String initial = middle.getText();
    String a=message.getText();
    if (initial != null)
        initial +=". ";
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source == submit)
    {

        message.setText(first.getText()+ ' ' +initial+last.getText());
        message.append('\n'+address.getText());
        message.append('\n'+city.getText()+", " +state.getText());
        message.append(' ' +zip.getText());
        message.append("\n\nYour message:\n"+a);
    }
    else if (source == reset)
    {
        message.setText("");
        first.setText("");
        middle.setText("");
        last.setText("");
        address.setText("");
        city.setText("");
        state.setText("");
        zip.setText("");

    }
    else if (source == enlarge)

    {
        message.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        message.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        message.setText(a);
    }
    else if (source == save)
    {
        try{


        File file=new File("savedMessage.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
                pw.println(message.getText());
                //message.setText("Print was successful")
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                System.out.println(message.getText());
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

}

Here is the code that was used to Fix the problem:

```
    else if (source == save)
    {
        try{
            f = new File("savedMessage.txt");
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f,true));
            bw.write(message.getText());
            if(f.canWrite()){
            System.out.println("Success");
            }
            }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    finally{

            try {
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: this is an Applet...There are restrictions on interacting with the filesystems from an Applet.

Comment: I wanted to thank All of You (Vincent Ramdhanie, EJP , Alex Wien) for helping me. I learned a lot through this and got it to write. The directory where it was being written wasn't the same as for other applets I wrote and that also confused me.

Thank you again, I don't know how to private message each of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PrintWriter` swallows exceptions. See the Javadoc. You need to call `checkError()`. Better still, use `BufferedWriter`, which doesn't swallow them. You're probably running up against an apple sandbox permission problem unless your applet is signed.

Answer (score -1):

First Tipp: close the file!
under catch ioexception you add a finally block

```
    File file = null;
    try {
       file = new File("filename.txt");
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    } finally {
       try {
            file.close();
        } catch (IoException ex2) { }

    }
```

Further check if file is writeable

```
if (!file.canWrite()) {
// forget it, cannit write
 }
```

Comment: Sorry to sound ignorant, but I tried that, and I also tried pw.close(); instead. Moved the File file=new File... line out of the try{

I am getting for file.close() undefined for type file and for pw.close(); I am getting pw cannot be resolved. If i move the PrinterWriter pw = new PrintWriter line outside of the try loop it tells me to add a try/catch for FileNotFound Exception which I already did....

Comment: PrintWriter pw; outside try, then pw = new Printwriter. inside try same for File file;

Comment: @user1890378 File file = null; PrintWriter pw = null;

Comment: Did the null. Added the canWritechec, added the finally close.
Now getting Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException in console

Comment: debug, check if pw could be null, sometimes before pw.close one has to check if pw != null; in your case i think it us nit neccesarry but i dont see yozr current cide

Comment: Checking File.canWrite() is truly futile. Better to just let the exception be thrown.

Comment: @EJP PrintWriter would not throw an exception, so he has to check, or use BufferedWritet

Comment: `new File(...)` does not throw `IOExcepions`, and `File.close()` does not exist.